# fs.writeFile start new line for each time it's called

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fs

When running this code it is working, however I would like it to make a new line of new data for each time it is ran.

So if it's run once it would go,
`Checked Status: ONLINE` then stop- however if the code is ran again it would make a new line directly under it with it again so I can keep an accurate log of status.

```js
var fs = require('fs');
    fs.writeFile('./status.log',
   `Checked Status: ${currentStatus}`
    ,()=>{
    logger.debug("AccessLog submitted!");
})
```

and yes, i'm aware- there are better ways of logging downtime, this is just the most convenient way for what i'm working with.

Comment: What do you mean "ran again".  There's no function here that you can call so how do you run it again?

Comment: @jfriend00 If the website is restarted it would record another "Checked Status:" underneath of the last "Checked Status:'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fs.writefile()` writes the entire file from scratch so you are overwriting the previous contents each time.  You should be using `fs.appendFile()` if you want to add more onto the end of the file.  And probably include a newline in what you're writing so each entry is its own line.